# Whereupon or thereupon?

Tags: word-choice

Marion arrives at the Bates Motel, whereupon Norman comes out to greet Marion.

Marion arrives at the Bates Motel, thereupon Norman comes out to greet Marion.

Are both words interchangeable in this case?

Comment: Do you think *where* and *there* are interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences are both grammatical, and the second is slightly problematic, for precisely the same reason that the following two sentences are both grammatical and the second is slightly problematic:

- Marion arrives at the Bates Motel, where Norman is waiting to greet Marion.
- Marion arrives at the Bates Motel, there Norman is waiting to greet Marion.

In the first sentence, *whereupon* (or *where* in my example) introduces a relative clause. The second sentence is really two sentences connected by a comma. This comma only works instead of a full stop (sort of) because what comes after it is long enough. One can write like that in a novel to indicate speed.

Comment: Aka [**comma splice**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).